# Looping through array contained in a hash

Tags: arrays, perl

So I have an object that contains an array:

```
package MyObject;

sub new {
    my($type) = @_;
    my $self->{Params}{Status}{Packages} = [];
}
```

I have a add new package sub which appends onto this "Package" array like:

```
sub add_package {
    my($self, $package_obj) = @_;

    push $self->{Params}{Status}{Packages}, $package;
}
```

Now when I go to find all the packages in my array I have issues. Whenever I try and pull out the packages like this:

```
foreach my $package($self->{Params}{Status}{Packages}) {
    # do something with $package. 
}
```

This only loops through one time. Now from what I understand the hash actually stores a pointer to the array so I tried to do:

```
foreach my $package(@$self->{Params}{Status}{Packages}) {
    # do something with $package. 
}
```

But then there is an error saying that $self is not an array. I did notice when I do:

```
scalar $self->{Params}{Status}{Packages};
```

It returns:

```
@ARRAY(0xSome Address);
```

What am I missing? And how can I use a `foreach` loop to go through my array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need to wrap it all in the array dereference block `@{}` so perl knows which portion you're trying to dereference...

```
for my $package (@{ $self->{Params}{Status}{Packages} }){
    print "$package\n";
}
```

Also, just to keep things consistent, I prefer to always deref the array with the block when extracting, or inserting:

```
push @{ $self->{Params}{Status}{Packages} }, $package;
```

UPDATE: As of 5.24.0+, autoderef (using `keys()`, `values()` or `each()` with a reference) will almost certainly be removed, and replaced with postfix references. However, using the `@{}` and `%{}` will continue to be supported, and is backwards compatible, so I'd recommend using them at all times.

Answer (score 4):

`$self->{Params}{Status}{Packages}` is a [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) to an array, in Perl terminology. When you have a reference to something, put the right character in front of it to [dereference it](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References). If the reference is more than just a name with possibly some sigils in front, you need to surround it with braces. It's a matter of precedence: `@$self->{Params}{Status}{Packages}` is parsed as `(@$self)->{Params}{Status}{Packages}`, but you need

```
@{$self->{Params}{Status}{Packages}}
```

i.e. the array referenced by the expression `$self->{Params}{Status}{Packages}`.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the clearest way to do this is to extract the array reference to a temporary scalar variable, which makes accessing the array very straightforward

```
my $packages = $self->{Params}{Status}{Packages};
for my $package ( @$packages ) {
    # do something with $package. 
}
```

Also, if you have `use strict` and `use warnings` enabled as you should, your `add_package` subroutine will produce the message

```
push on reference is experimental
```

This isn't something you can safely ignore. Experimental features may change their behaviour or disappear completely in later versions of Perl, and it is unwise to make use of them in production code. You can fix your subroutine in a similar way, like this

```
sub add_package {
    my ($self, $package_obj) = @_;

    my $packages = $self->{Params}{Status}{Packages};
    push @$packages, $package;
}
```